# What is this line of perl doing?

Tags: perl

I don't understand what that return statement is doing.

```
my %config = (
  'name'       => 'blah',
);

return wantarray ? %config : \%config;
```

In particular, the \% part is confusing me.

Comment: The `return wantarray ? @array : \@array` is a widespread idiom so that a caller of the function can do both `my $array_ref = the_sub()` and `my @array = the_sub()`. (The `\ ` is the reference operator). There are some cases where this can lead to weird results; I find it preferable to always return the reference.

Comment: Most notably, trying to use the function as a hash value (`$h = { key => the_sub() }`) will not work as expected!

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [perldoc -f wantarray](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html):

> Returns true if the context of the currently executing subroutine or eval is looking for a list value. Returns false if the context is looking for a scalar. Returns the undefined value if the context is looking for no value (void context).

If the caller doesn't want a list, the `\%config` syntax returns a reference to the `%config` hash instead of the hash flattened to a list of alternating keys and values.

Comment: so \ is just a reference operator?

Comment: @SinanÜnür your edits are not themselves correct - `wantarray` is `true` if the caller wants a hash, too.

Comment: @Alnitak, it's true if the caller wants a *list*. Unfortunately it is badly named.

Comment: @ysth that edit of yours may need explaining.  IMHO, to all intents and purposes, if you `return %foo` and assign the result to `%bar`, then you've returned (a copy of) a hash.  If you assigned the result to `@bar` then you do indeed get a flattened list of keys and values.

Comment: but it is the list assignment that provides the context that flattens %foo; if you `return %foo` and assign the result to `$bar` you get something very different.  this makes "returns a hash" an ambiguous statement (as well as never describing what actually happens in either case).  does that help?

Comment: @ysth but surely the point of the `wantarray` test is that if you _do_ assign the result to `$bar` that you end up with the _reference to the hash_.

Comment: @ysth and FWIW, I do understand the point you're trying to make, but think it bears more explanation for future readers.

Comment: and if you don't, you end up with a list; it is still incorrect to say "returns a hash"

Comment: but it's your answer; change it back if you want and I won't mess with it.